# using mediaqueries to work on ie

Tags: jquery, css, media-queries

I have a `css` file which contains all my `css` and the `css` for the media queries. i used the local hard drive to test my page.it works fine in all the modern browsers except `ie 7 8`.
i included the script `response.js` in my `html header` which is in my hard drive, but still it doesnt work.if anyone could help.it would be really great.thanks

following is how i added the script and the `css` to my `html header`.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="shane.css"/>
<script src="respond.src.js"></script>
```

Comment: *in my hard drive* ... where in your hard drive? Is there a 404 relating to `respond.src.js` ?

Comment: its in the same folder where my html and css files are.when i load the page in ie 7 follwing warning appear in the console `SCRIPT5: Access is denied.respond.src.js, line 287 character 4`
 i used the js which was in the github https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond/blob/master/respond.src.js

Comment: Did you test in the latest version of Google chrome as well? it looks like some cross domain security when you open the html file directly in the browser. Can it run if you use a webserver?

Comment: yes bart i did.and it works fine.i dont have a web server installed in my comp.is it necessary to have one.will the script work if i use a server? i did everything locally and tested.but i used media-query.js aswell..and it works.but it lacks performance and there are some issues with the page navigation.in 400px to 500px browser width, i cannot scroll down the page. it automatically comes to the top. thats why i tried using respond.js

Comment: i used xampp and it works fine now..thanks every1 for taking time to reply..im kinda new to the whole web development field.sorry if i raised unnecessary probs..